# Joining two csv data in dataflow python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two csv files - I want to do full join in data flow

the two csv files I read as PCollection

csv1

columns `A | B | C | D | E`

csv2

columns `A | B | C | F | G`

I need to join the two P collection based on key `A,B` and get the resulting p collection like below

columns `A | B | C | D | E | F | G`

Trial 1

```
{'left': P_collection_1, 'right': P_collection_2}
            | ' Combine' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
            | ' ExtractValues' >> beam.Values()
```

This is basically like a full join in sql

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can indeed use CoGroupBykey:

Applying the [Apache Beam Programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms)'s example of phones and emails to your case, you can try to feed CoGroupByKey with a PCollection of 'C,D,E's, keyed with 'A,B's, and a PCollection of 'F,G's, also keyed with 'A,B's.

To make it a little clearer, the elements in each PCollection must be tuples, with their first element an 'A,B' key, and the second a 'C,D,E' or 'F,G' value:

```
PColl1 = PCollection(
('2,4', '1,2,5'),
('1,10', '4,4,9'),
...) # this is the PCollection of CDE's

PColl2 = PCollection(
('2,4', '30,3'),
('20,1', '2,1'),
...) # this is the PCollection of FG's
```

(The PCollection notation is just here to illustrate)

Then we would apply :

```
join = {'CDE': PColl1, 'FG': Pcoll2} | beam.CoGroupByKey()
```

As per the programming guide, result should be:

```
PCollection(
('2,4', {
        'CDE': ['1,2,5'],
        'FG': ['30,3']
        }
),
('1,10', {
        'CDE': ['4,4,9']
       }
),
('20,1', {
        'FG': ['2,1']
        }
),
...)
```

If A and B take value 2,4 more than once in a same file, it shouldn't be a problem, we should have several values in CDE or in FG.